# Using JDBC parameters with instsrv.exe and servany.exe

Tags: java, windows, jdbc, windows-services, windows-dev-center

I have a java application that has been running as a service forever using servant.exe. Recently I made some changes that required adding some parameters, specifically: -cp .;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar" -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\auth\x64"

If I copy and paste the parameters from RegEdit in to a batch file, it will work fine except that stopping the service doesn't kill the application. When I try to start the service, srvany starts but not java. There is no error message or anything to indicate what went wrong. The server is Windows 2008 r2.

The part that it blows up on is -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\auth\x64". I tried changing x64 to x86 but that didn't help. Any ideas?

The connection uses Windows authentication. It uses the correct identity when the parameters are in a batch file that the srvany.exe is configured to run in the registry. There is something about the parameter 'Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\auth\x64"' that srvany.exe doesn't like.

Comment: I don't see why you need JNDI and native code to connect to SQL Server.  The type IV JDBC driver is enough.

Comment: Question title should be improved?

Comment: What is the connection URL used in your application, and as which user is the service running. One of the possible problems is that you are using Windows authentication, but the user is a local user instead of a domain user, or the domain user isn't allowed to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: It is using Windows Authentication, hence the need for Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\auth\x64". It runs fine as a service and uses the correct windows identity when the installed service is configured to run the commanding a batch file. I don't know what about that parameter srvany doesn't like.